# Remove objects from an array before calling the API

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I'm creating a table view which is hooked to an API. However, I'm having trouble with doing a refresh on pull. I've added the logic, however I can't seem to delete all the objects in the array before making a new api call.

Here is my array

```
 var recentArray = Array<News>()
```

UIRefreshControl function:

```
func refresh(sender: UIRefreshControl){

    lastObjectIndex=0
    // remove all objects

    getRecent()
    self.tableVIew.reloadData()
    self.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
}
```

How can i remove all objects in my array before calling `getRecent`, which adds an object to the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reset your array like this:

```
recentArray = []
```

The compiler already knows the type of the array objects, so there's no need to do anything else.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can remove all objects by calling

```
recentArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can removed all object by adding following code befor `getRecent` called.

```
var array = [0, 1, 2, 3]
array.removeAll()
let count = array.count
// count is 0
```

Hope this will help you.